# google default service account did not have permission for bq utility

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a VM instance having default service account attached.

While doing bq ls on that instance throws error as below:

```
(airflow) [root@airflow-qa-master ~]# bq ls

BigQuery error in ls operation: Insufficient Permission
```

So I gave other permissions to that default service account listed below:

```
BigQuery Admin

BigQuery Data Editor

BigQuery Data Owner

BigQuery Data Viewer

Compute Admin

Compute Storage Admin

Editor

Owner
```

Still it is throwing Invalid credentials issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Default scope for an instance does not allow BigQuery access. There are two considerations for whether an API is usable on GCE, first being whether the attached service account is authorized to perform those actions. Second is whether the instance is allowed to perform those actions.

You can change the scope of an instance using [this part of their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes).

Comment: can you elaborate on the two considerations mentioned above

Comment: Service accounts can have permissions/roles assigned to them like the ones you referenced. BigQuery Admin, GCS Viewer, etc.

However Instances themselves have the ability to limit what APIs can be called from the instance. This allows an extra layer of protection if for example you know an instance will only ever need to talk to GCS you can limit it from calling any google APIs besides GCS. Ideally you would use a limited service account, but it can be nice. 

I'm suggesting that your GCE Instance Scope does not allow the BigQuery APIs.